# how can I get the li length in UL which hoverd

Tags: jquery, html, css

Please check this URL.
http://devsite.itrheat.com/products/marin-heating-systems/

What I want to know is that 
when you hover the left menu such as "RV, Trailer", "Marine Heating..", you can see the sub-menu such as "Oasis NE", "Oasis NE-S..".

So I want to get the sub-menu length.
Because I want to make the sub-menu width samely.
so if I got the sub-menu length, I can make the their width samely(sub-menu width=100%/sub-menu length)

Please help me.

Comment: [Read how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

This code should help you accomplish this.

```
var sublinks = document.getElementsByClassName("product-sub-links")[0];
var activeUl = sublinks.getElementsByClassName("active")[0];
var liLength = activeUl.getElementsByTagName("li").length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you map your main menu to sub menu via main-id => sub-class than you can do:

```
$('.product-top-links li').mouseenter(function () {
     var list = $('.product-sub-links .'+$(this).attr('id')+' li');

     // total elements as "length as count of elements"
     console.log(list.length);

     var totalWidth = 0;

     $.each(list, function () {
         totalWidth += $(this).outerWidth();
     });

     // total width as "length as all elements combined width"
     console.log(totalWidth);
});
```

Just make sure you first show your sub-menu, and only then count width, as hidden elements (even if it's hidden by parent) will have `0px` width